# keras with TensorFlow GPU, CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED hyper parameters search

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am working with Keras with TensorFlow back end.

I writing search script for tuning my CuDDNNLSTM hyper parameters .

After creating ~10 different CuDDNNLSTM networks I received the error:
`tensorflow\stream_executer\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:1108 could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED` during the search process.
in : tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run,_do_run,_do_call

OS: WIN10 64x

Python: 3.6.5

Keras version : 2.1.6

Tensorflow/GPU: 1.10.0

CUDA:9.0

cuddn:7.3

GPU: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

May someone encounter in that problem ?

Comment: Are the said 10 networks running simultaneously ?

Comment: No, I training one network with hyper parameters , then I training another network with other hyper parameter etc' in the ~10th network I received that error , all the networks are training in loop that select in each step different hyper parameters